# How to get the sunshine and sunlight in my house

Tags: windows, skylight

I am living in house in which the sun is not overlooking through the window at all, Is there a way to make overlook at least partially inside the house.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question really has a practical answer. Put in new windows or a skylight? Do you have a solid door that you could replace with one containing a window? Put a bunch of angled mirrors in your yard aimed at your windows?

Comment: are there trees outside that you can trim to let light in?

Comment: Does sunlight hit your roof and are you an the top floor?

Comment: @Doresoom Mirrors? [Some inspriation](http://www.theguardian.com/world/video/2013/oct/29/giant-mirrors-reflect-sun-video).

Comment: Get one of these: http://www.tumbleweedhouses.com/products/elm/

Comment: @gregmac: [As long as it's not parabolic!](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_furnace#/image/File:Four_solaire_001.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Tubular skylights**, a [suntube](http://campdesigns.blogspot.com/2011/01/sun-tubes-solar-pipes-and-skylights-oh.html) in use and available from [Solatube](http://www.solatube.com/). There's roofing and carpentry involved but no framing needed. They're the only way to have a skylight with an attic above without blowing out your ceiling. Cut 2 holes, flash it to the roof, enjoy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These things are awesome!

Comment: I have the opposite opinion.  My aunt has these and they are useless IMHO.